# Maven pom looking for resources outside of jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I'm having trouble creating an executable jar with all dependancies and resources packaged in it. So far I have everything inside the jar, but it is looking for the resources OUTside the jar.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
MyProject
----images
----resources
----src
----...
```

I'm able to Create the Executable Jar with dependancies packaged in, and the resources are packaged as well, however it is still looking for the resources in the "resources" folder and not IN the JAR.

The jar looks like this:

```
MyProject.jar
----images
----resources
----...
```

When I try run it, I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../MyProject/target/resources/default-style.xml (No such file or directory)
```

So my problem is this: **my dependancies and resources are packaged in the jar like I want, but upon execution it's looking for "resources/" in the "target/" folder and NOT in the JAR.**

Here's my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<!-- MyProject INFO -->
<groupId>Main</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-beta</version>
<name>MyProject</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<!-- DEPENDANCIES -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>custom</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jgraphx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>   
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<!-- RESOURCES -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/images</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <targetPath>images</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
<!--  For Java 6, you need to configure the maven-compiler-plugin. Add this to your pom.xml: -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
<!-- CREATE EXECUTABLE JAR WITH DEPENDANCIES -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
        <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
          <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

EDIT: Looks like it might be my code instead. I'll take a look, thanks! (My company's proxy blocks most of stackoverflow so I can't reply to comments >.< That's why I'm writing it here. Thanks Jigar Joshi and Aurand!)

Comment: It is your code that is reading file from specific fixed location, I think

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with maven but with your code.  Please post the lines of code that are throwing the exception.

Comment: Chances are, you're trying to read a file inside of a JAR and not using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` which you must do if you want to access a resource that's packaged in your JAR reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the java build path. The default output folder for the resources might be incorrect. May be that is why resource contents are not copied properly.